# T-SQL query equivalent of trim (trailing 'C' from 'CRIC2')

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to discard trailing characters from 'C' from the variable string (IS18002TBB1C2).

Need equivalent of

```
    `TRIM` (TRAILING 'C' FROM 'IS18002TBB1C2')
```

in SQL Server

Expecting ans is IS18002TBB1

Comment: Sample data and expected out will be more useful these days!

Comment: First or second C

Comment: Trailing - second C

Comment: if there are more than two `C` what is your expect result?

Comment: Result expected is CRI

Comment: What DBMS supports the original syntax?

Comment: @dnoeth, shouldn't they all - it's ANSI SQL...? At least DB2, Postgresql, Mimer SQL and Oracle do, and probably some more.

Comment: `TRIM (TRAILING 'C' FROM 'CRICT2')` returns `'CRICT2'`, since there is no trailing `'C'` character to remove. (The last character is `'2'`.)

Comment: @jarlh: That's what I mean, Standard SQL will not return what the OP expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REVERSE()` in combination with `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX`

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR (10)='CRICT2'

SELECT LEFT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX('C',REVERSE(@Str)))
```

For [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6734a446bc2aa63ae2a7ef7038ab52cd)

Comment: yes sorry that was my mistake in declaration

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you generally want to remove the substring beginning with the *last* `C`, we can try using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` on the reverse of the string:

```
SELECT
     col,
     REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(col),
             CHARINDEX('C', REVERSE(col)) + 1,
             LEN(col))) AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: for  value(IS18002TBB1C2),  expected ans is IS18002TBB1 but it gave IS18002TBB. The 1 is missing

Comment: @ShankarNaren No, the [correct output is there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c7a841c0266138a295e537d5a65d3514), check the demo.

Comment: Yes sorry that was my mistake in declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, The other Answer was using less functions so I have chosen that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select reverse(substring(reverse('ABCCCC')                 
                        ,patindex('%[^C]%',reverse('ABCCCC'))
                        ,len('ABCCCC')
                        )
               )
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer.

Comment: The following query select reverse(substring(reverse('ABCCCC')                 
      ,patindex('%[^C]%',reverse('ABCCCC'))
      ,len('ABCCCC')
      )
               ) does the following. 1. reverse the string. 2. check for the position of the first non "C" pattern. 3. substring it from that point onwards. 4. reverse it back to the original version.